# Username with backslash

Tags: escaping, liquibase, backslash

I have tried both liquibase through the gradle plugin, and liquibase standalone to run updates on a database, with a user that has a back slash in the username.

I always get a "Login failed" error. If I try to connect to the same database with another user that does not have the backslash it works, but I really need to connect using the one with the backslash.

You can see more details here: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-gradle-plugin/issues/62

Any ideas on how I can try to escape the backslash?
I tried using quotation, and double backslash, or even, in desperation, tried multiple backslashes, but to no avail.

Comment: Have you tryed `liquibase {
 activities {
  main {
   changeLogFile "$config.db.changeLogFile"
   url 'jdbc:sqlserver://servername:1433;databaseName=dbname'
   username 'org\username'
   password 'password'
  }
 }
}`

Comment: @Zorglube If I try with only one \ then gradle will not compile correctly. Why I try to run a task I get the error:

groovyjarjarantlr.TokenStreamIOException: Did not find four digit hex character code. line: 63 col:17

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not related Liquibase, it was in trying to login to an MSSql database using domain credentials.

For any future users affected with this issue, I changed my connection string:

```
liquibase {
    activities {
        main {
            changeLogFile "$config.db.changeLogFile"
            url 'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://servername:1433;databaseName=dbName;domain=org;useNTLMv2=true;'
            username "username"
            password 'password'
        }
    }
}
```

So the domain is no longer declared in the username, but in the url. Also the change to jdbc:jtds:sqlserver means that Liquibase is using the jtds driver to connect with the database, which seems to be supported just fine.

I also did a push to try to use Kerberos integrated security authentication, but in the end I went with the NTLM authentication, as above. Anyway if that is of interest to you, go and check it out.

I also leave some interesting articles that helped me:
https://kontext.tech/docs/DotNetEssential/p/jdbc-integrated-security-ntlm-and-kerberos-authentication-for-sql-server
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2015/01/09/jdbc-this-driver-is-not-configured-for-integrated-authentication/